# Weka Multilayer Perceptron Taking a Long Time to Complete?

Tags: weka, multi-layer

I've got 5 attributes and 3310 instances (hidden layers = a) using a percentage split of 70%, however I've left it for a number of hours now and it is still stuck on 'Building model on training data'. Is this normal? How long can I expect to wait until it completes.

Is there anything I can do to make it run any faster?

Comment: Have you tried testing this classifier (a) on a standard dataset and (b) on a smaller subset of your dataset?

Comment: Not normal.  Are your predictors nominal, with a large number of alternative values? That might increase the time substantially.